# VSCode, Prettier конфигурации

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

немогу настроить Prettier так чтоб можно было переносить код на след строку, Prettier переносит мой код в одну строку как от этого избавится? еще не могу переносить в другую строку пустые скобки и оставлять их пустыми. Какие конфигурации нужно изменить чтоб это было доступно[image: скрин]

Comment: `printWidth`...

Comment: а какое значение должно быть? у меня стоит 80

Comment: printWidth - это размещение символов в строку как я понял так если я его изменю и поставлю на пример 60 то у меня вся структура кода будет изменена а это не совсем то что я хочу, мне нужно переносить chaining в другую строку а не весь код